# C# WPF DataGrid Binding from another class

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a window in which I want to autogenerate ObservableCollection from another class. When setting it up in back-end, everything works properly:

```
XAML

<DataGrid Name="ResidenceGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>

CS
public ResidenceWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ResidenceGrid.ItemsSource = Manager.ResidenceList;
    }
```

But the moment I try to do it all in xaml, the DataGrid appears blank:

```
XAML

<DataGrid Name="ResidenceGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Manager.ResidenceList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>

CS
public ResidenceWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

The ObservableCollection called from another class just in case:

```
static class Manager
{
    public static ObservableCollection<Residence> ResidenceList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Residence>();
}
```

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Binding, you need to set DataContext inside your ResidenceWindow.

Ex:

```
public ResidenceWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = Manager;
}
```

https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/using-the-datacontext/

Comment: The Manager class is static though. If I try this, I get "Manager is a type, which is not valid in the given context." Any way to bypass this? I tried setting DataContext in MainWindow in xaml, but to no avail. No error, but empty DataGrid nonetheless.

Comment: You can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880492/can-i-set-a-datacontext-to-a-static-class

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to the static `Manager.ResidenceList` property like this:

```
<DataGrid Name="ResidenceGrid" ItemsSource="{x:Static local:Manager.ResidenceList}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
```

And there is no reason to set the `Mode` of the binding for the `ItemsSource` property to `TwoWay` nor set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged`.